# Symantec Endpoint Protection - Replicating my sites

Tags: windows, replication, anti-virus, symantec

I have Symantec Endpoint Protection Installed on a Windows Server 2003 machine, this has VPN links to two other offices with Windows Server 2003 machines. I am trying to replicate Symantec Endpoint Protection to these machines.

I have installed the software at the other sites and started the replication wizard, but it is still going and  I started it a few days ago. I know it is doing something because the out.log file is updated every 10 minutes.

Does anyone have any experience of setting this up or any idea how long the process will take?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: What does the out.log file say?

Comment: I. 06/02 09:31:07. Starting checkpoint of "sem5" (sem5.db) at Tue Jun 02 2009 09:31
I. 06/02 09:31:07. Finished checkpoint of "sem5" (sem5.db) at Tue Jun 02 2009 09:31. This just repeats every 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated Symantec Endpoint Protection from the Symantec Server to the Clients in the past, and it worked great on a LAN enviroment. I wonder if the VPN is the catch. I would be willing to bet this weird port action isn't allowed by your VPN tunnels. What you may look at is just coping the files off the server from the \'YourSymantecServerIPAddress'\vphome\CLT-INST share folder that shold be setup on the Symantec Server.  You can hope that once you install the files from the share, it should point back to the server for updates and these take place on only a single port, much eaiser to track down what needs to be opened up.

http://service1.symantec.com/SUPPORT/ent-security.nsf/docid/2007071909500548 says:

"**What ports do clients use to communicate with the Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager?**
Clients use the default ephemeral ports (1024 to 65535) for TCP for network communications. The ephemeral port range that is used, however, rarely exceeds 5000."

Comment: I am not sure if that would work because I have copied the install files onto the remote server, it is just the database that it is trying to replicate SQL to Embedded. I will investigate further though.

Comment: ah I see. I thought you were just trying to get it installed. As you have said, I would still look at ports. Some VPN's don't by default send all traffic back and forth, but only selected kinds. I could see the remote end blocking the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Most Symantec purchases include phone support by default, this might be one of those times where it would be worth calling them.  They've helped me out a couple of times.